# Anyway to save contents of iPhone app to a PC?

Tags: ios, applications

I bought a video course on my iPhone, the app essentially launches the videos in the standard iPhone video player.

I'm selling my iPhone and would like to recover the videos, or at least preserve the app data until I can figure out how to extract the videos from it.

I currently sync to Windows. But I have a MacBook as well if it matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try [i-FunBox](http://www.i-funbox.com/) it allows you to save apps to your computer without using iTunes.

Comment: There's a version for the mac too [iFunbox Mac][1]

personally I use ecamms [Phoneview][2] which is OSX only.


  [1]: http://ifunboxmac.com/
  [2]: http://www.ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/

Answer (score 1):

### [iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/)

is a free utility that will let you mount your iOS device in Windows and browse its file structure. Any document file you find can be drag-copied to the hard drive of your PC in Windows Explorer.

The iExplorer company also has several commercial apps for Windows that have additional functionality for dealing with media on iOS devices.

Answer (score 0):

If the videos are contained WITHIN an app they are *protected* (technically they are sandboxed) even if the app uses the standard iPhone player.

These videos cannot be exported like photos or videos in the photo app.